# How to save the value of an DropDown in an Variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

After searching and trying with the (not so great) spyder debugger I have stil no clue why my Code isnt working.
I want to select something from a drop down and later give a return depending on what was choosen.

Should be quiet simple. The window works, I can select a value but when I select klick the button the Error:

NameError: name 'Selected_Report' is not defined

But I do define this variable in the select_Report function(?) I assume there is some silly mistake, I just cant see it.

Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *

REPORTS = [
"Alle Mitarbeiter",
"Alle Projekte",
"Alle Skills"
]

ReportSelection_Win = Tk()

variable = StringVar(ReportSelection_Win)
variable.set(REPORTS[0]) # default value

Lbl_Headline = Label(ReportSelection_Win, text = "Bitte wählen Sie einen Report")#Create Label
Lbl_Headline.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10) #Show Label

Drop_Reports = OptionMenu(ReportSelection_Win, variable, *REPORTS)
Drop_Reports.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=0)

def Select_Report():
    Selected_Report = variable.get()
    ReportSelection_Win.destroy()

Btt_Confirm_2 = Button(ReportSelection_Win, text="Auswählen", command=Select_Report)
Btt_Confirm_2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)



ReportSelection_Win.mainloop()


#----------------------------Selected Report-----------------------------------

if Selected_Report == "Alle Mitarbeiter":
  print("Alle Mitarbeiter")

elif Selected_Report == "Alle Projekte":
  print("Alle Projekte")

elif Selected_Report == "Alle Skills":
  print("Alle Skills")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell python that you are using global variable . You do that with 
`global [variable name]`

```py
from tkinter import *

REPORTS = [
"Alle Mitarbeiter",
"Alle Projekte",
"Alle Skills"
]


ReportSelection_Win = Tk()

variable = StringVar(ReportSelection_Win)
variable.set(REPORTS[0]) # default value

Lbl_Headline = Label(ReportSelection_Win, text = "Bitte wählen Sie einen Report")#Create Label
Lbl_Headline.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10) #Show Label

Drop_Reports = OptionMenu(ReportSelection_Win, variable, *REPORTS)
Drop_Reports.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=0)

def Select_Report():
    global Selected_Report
    Selected_Report = variable.get()
    ReportSelection_Win.destroy()

Btt_Confirm_2 = Button(ReportSelection_Win, text="Auswählen", command=Select_Report)
Btt_Confirm_2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)



ReportSelection_Win.mainloop()


#----------------------------Selected Report-----------------------------------

print(Selected_Report)
```